# SQL Stored procedure display output of RAISE INFO in Python

Tags: python, sql, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, display

I have a stored procedure as below, when i run the procedure in DBeaver then i am able to see the output of `RAISE INFO` in the console, but i want to log the same output when Running from python
using `cursor.execute('call testing_proc()')`

How can i do that ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testing_proc()
AS $$
    
     declare
    cntr int :=1 ; 
       max_cntr int := 200; 
        time_counter timestamp ; 
        perc_cmp real; 
        time_taken real ; 
        tempp int ;
        begin 
        time_counter = getdate() ; 
        while( cntr <= max_cntr) 
        loop 
            INSERT INTO table2 SELECT *  FROM table1; 
            
            perc_cmp = cntr*100/max_cntr ;
            
            RAISE INFO '****Total  Processed = %
                            Total  Processed = % ***',cntr , perc_cmp; 
            cntr = cntr+1; 
        end loop; 
        time_taken = datediff(second, time_counter , getdate() ); 
        RAISE INFO '******* Total Time Taken = % seconds ', time_taken ; 
    end; 

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

PS: please don't bogged down in the details of understanding the code i just shared that for the reference

Comment: I doubt it's possible. When you execute a query, the only data that comes out are result sets that come from queries like `SELECT`. How would you expect the cursor to return info messages? You could raise an error, then it would cause the procedure to fail and `cursor.execute()` will raise a Python exception.

Comment: if there is any other way other than cursor ?

Comment: You can declare output parameters  and set value inside stored procedure.Also depending on use case you can use RETURN in stored procedure.

Comment: Why note just `RETURN` the time taken, or the string with that message, rather than using RAISE INFO?

Comment: I have too many of such output and changing with loop and return value will be available at the end and above proc was just a demo my actual one is too complex